# Fatal: ambiguous argument '<branch_name>': both revision and filename

Tags: git, version-control

Here is what I did:

- I ran `git checkout -b branch_name`.
- I made some commits on `branch_name`.
- I checked out the `master` branch and did a fast-foward merge.

When I run `git log branch_name --oneline`, I get the following message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'branch_name': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's telling you that you have a branch named 'branch_name' and also a file or a directory named 'branch_name'.

If you want the command to treat 'branch_name' as a branch use

```
git log --oneline branch_name --
```

if you want it to treat 'branch_name' as a file use

```
git log --oneline -- branch_name
```

Comment: How is this more informative than the error message itself?

Comment: Some people have difficulty understanding that a `branch` is a `revision` so I tried to spell that out.

Comment: Note that using `gitk branch_name` only reports the `Ambiguous argument` line, not how to fix it. This answer applies to `gitk` as well.

Comment: @Jubobs I got this error while running `git show` on a file at a specific revision (e.g. `git show HEAD:some/file.txt`). The error message (`fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD:some/file.txt': both revision and filename`) in that case wasn't particularly helpful, especially since `git show HEAD -- some/file.txt` does something completely different.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Fair enough :)

Answer (score 3):

If in case any one faced when trying the following and got above error, here is the fix

Problem:-

```
#In master branch
git checkout -b feature-a

#changed to feature-a branch
vi a.txt
git commit -m "adding a file" a.txt
git push
git diff master

fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Solution:-

```
git diff origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I work with diff's with something like this:

```
git diff -r 2e706c4dd3 -r 838112ed50 > codereview.txt
```

...to make a nice codereview.txt file.  Well, I accidentally ran this:

```
git diff -r 2e706c4dd3 -r 838112ed50 > 838112ed50
```

This makes the file `838112ed50` itself, which, then, makes the `git diff` command ambiguous, about whether I am trying to diff a file or a branch.